# phpMyAdmin - Cannot login, Either Forgot Password or issue with No Password

Tags: phpmyadmin, password

I have just used phpMyAdmin on my local machine for the first time in about 6 months. I am using `localhost:8080`. I thought I had no password, however when it asks me to log in I put:

```
username: root
password: [I leave this blank]
```

I cannot log in.

I do not think I created a new password 6 months ago, but there is a small possibility I did and have now forgotten about it.

So now I am locked out of my phpMyAdmin.

I have tried the solution here by RiggsFolly:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070501/regaining-access-to-lost-mysql-password-for-phpmyadmin-on-wamp

But no luck.

I do the following:

Stop the mysql service

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
```

Edit the my.ini file

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Find the wampmysqld64 section in the ini file
Add this line directly after that section heading

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Restart the mysql service.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Open the MySQL console

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
```

It asks for the password, but I just tap enter and it seems to skip that.
I then get the MySQL> prompt.

I have version 5.7.9 so I enter the following:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
```

Sometimes it gives a warning, but I do not know what.

I should then do the following two commands now, but I get a problem:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It says (after the `ALTER USER` bit):

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

If I do the obvious thing and stop the service as above and then alter the .ini file again to remove that line. I then restart and retype the `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;` command. This time it complains saying I should have just done a password change to make this command. (It basically thinks I have not just done the password change as I have had to shut down the system, alter the ini file and then restart in between the commands.)

So I am stuck at this point getting nowhere fast.

If the `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` had worked, I would have then have had to continue with the following:

At the console mysql> prompt I would then need to type:

```
quit;
```

Then stop the mysql service:

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
```

Edit the my.ini file

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

Find the wampmysqld64 section in the ini file
Remove the skip-grant-tables parameter we added earlier.

Restart the mysql service.

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

However, as I am stuck at those two commands with no workaround I remain locked out of phpMyAdmin

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because you have already asked the same question on Stack Overflow, granted that the Pro Webmasters has appended information on what you've tried but it does not make the question any more unique and is considered cross-posting. Since the issue you have is in regards of the operating system and SQL then the more suitable stack would be Server Fault... however you should check for duplicates before reposting and ensure that you have removed any questions on other stacks related to this issue.